# How to navigate to the last child of a hierarchical data stored in SQL database based on the JSON passed in the request body in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have a need to get the last child of a hierarchy based on the JSON data passed from the request body.
The request body looks like this:

```
{
    "hierarchy": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A",
            "level": 0,
            "labels": [
                "grandparent",
                "parent",
                "child"
            ],
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "B",
                    "level": 1,
                    "action": "kill",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "C",
                            "level": 2,
                            "action": "kill",
                            "categories": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "action": "kill"
        }
    ]
}
```

The data will be stored in the SQL database like this:

[image]

Based on the data sent from the req body, I need to navigate to the last child in the database , in this case: C and then delete them.

Currently Im using this:

```
const killfamily = async (id, transaction, header = {}) => {
    //need recursive method here 
    await family.destroy({ where: { parent_id: id }, transaction: transaction });
    const result = await family.destroy({ where: { fid: id }, transaction: transaction });
    return result;
```

Current approach is not working as im trying to delete the parent first. I want to achieve this using recursive method i.e Go to the inner most/ last child and perform destroy on it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: is it ever possible that the request could have multiple children at the deepest level? do you also want to delete B and A? or only C?

Comment: You have `action: 'kill'` at multiple levels in your input.  Do you want to ignore everything not at the deepest level?

Comment: I want to delete the entire family when I pass in the payload